# Calculate sum of last n games Mysql

Tags: mysql, forms, sum

I keep track of all european football leagues. But now I want a table with all of the teams and next to it there total goals scored and totals goals against of their last 5 games.

My results table has the following columns:Match_id | Date | home team| Away team | Home Goals | Away goals

So what would the code be for this issue as you have to check both the `home team` column and `away team` column to find their last 5 match results??

Pls HELP :D

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: total goal means total goals against all teams or opponent team wise. You need to elaborate your question.

Comment: Totals goals for a team, so for example:

1. 04/08/2015 Team A Team B 2 0
2. 05/08/2015 Team C Team A 1 2 
3. 06/08/2015 Team B Team C 3 0 
4. 10/08/2015 Team A Team B 2 0
5. 11/08/2015 Team C Team A 1 2 
6. 12/08/2015 Team B Team C 3 0 

Than I would like a table for the last 3 games like:
Team A 6 (goals scored )
Team B ... ( goals scored)
Team C ... (goals scored)

And next to it the number of last 3 games goals AGAINST

Comment: @yellow Bird. I'm still "studying" mysql but my knowledge isn't that great so far. I can do some basic things but for this i really need some help

Answer (score 0):

Getting all goals for a team when it's a home/away team in the last 5 games would be:

```
SELECT home_team as team, sum(home_goals) as goals FROM tbl a WHERE match_id IN (SELECT match_id FROM tbl b WHERE b.home_team = a.home_team ORDER BY date desc limit 5) GROUP BY home_team
```

Similarly you can get the away team (lets call this query Q_home and the equivalent for the away team Q_away).

So overall you'd want to do something like:

```
SELECT team, a.goals+b.goals FROM <Q_home> a JOIN <Q_away> b ON a.team=b.team
```

Not really sure if this would work but this is the general idea.

Comment: Tnx for the quick response! Will try this and get back to you.